# Stripe Connect firebase functions for creating seller account

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I'm using Firebase functions for creating seller account but I don't know how to create seller account and what to put in the redirect_url
I followed some tutorials and wrote the below code
Let me know what changes should I do to open seller account registration with url_launcher
Thanks

```
const stripeAccount = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  const { method } = req
  if (method === "GET") {
    // CREATE CONNECTED ACCOUNT
    const { mobile } = req.query
    const account = await stripe.accounts.create({
      type: "express",
    })
    const accountLinks = await stripe.accountLinks.create({
      account: account.id,
      refresh_url:, <--  What to put here
      return_url:, <--  What to put here
      type: "account_onboarding",
    })
    if (mobile) {
      // In case of request generated from the flutter app, return a json response
      res.status(200).json({ success: true, url: accountLinks.url })
    } else {
      // In case of request generated from the web app, redirect
      res.redirect(accountLinks.url)
    }
  } else if (method === "DELETE") {
    // Delete the Connected Account having provided ID
    const {
      query: { id },
    } = req
    console.log(id)
    const deleted = await stripe.accounts.del(id)
    res.status(200).json({ message: "account deleted successfully", deleted })
  } else if (method === "POST") {
    // Retrieve the Connected Account for the provided ID
    // I know it shouldn't be a POST call. Don't judge :D I had a lot on my plate
    const account = await stripe.accounts.retrieve(req.query.id)
    res.status(200).json({ account })
  }


  const stripeReAuth = async (req, res) => {
    const { account_id: accountId } = req.query

    const accountLinks = await stripe.accountLinks.create({
      account: accountId,
      refresh_url:   <-- Here 
      return_url: , <-- Here 
      type: "account_onboarding",
    })
    res.redirect(accountLinks.url)
  }

})
```

This is my flutter code, I'm retrieving the return_url and launching it with url_launcher

```
class StripeBackendService {
  static String apiBase = '{function address}/stripeAccount';
  static String createAccountUrl =
      '$apiBase/account?mobile=true';
  static String checkoutSessionUrl =
      '${StripeBackendService.apiBase}/checkout-session?mobile=true';
  static Map<String, String> headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'};

 void createSellerAccount() async {
    var url = Uri.parse(StripeBackendService.createAccountUrl);
    var response = await http.get(url, headers: StripeBackendService.headers);
    Map<String, dynamic> body = jsonDecode(response.body.toString());
   await canLaunch(body['url']) ? await launch(body['url']) : throw 'Error'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The refresh url should point to an address that retries the creation of the stripe connect account, in case your current http function returns an expired link. The return url is the address that the potential stripe connect user gets sent to after the stripe onboarding is complete. In knowing that address you can use the webview controller to jump back to the app when reaching that return-url endpoint.

Comment: can you share some code of firebase function "..? Thanks